# Contenteditable math element?

Tags: html, math, contenteditable

I know that we can create contentEditable `p`, `div`, `span`, etc........

But how can I create a contentEditable `math` element, like:

```
<math contenteditable>
.....
</math>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `contenteditable` attribute is part of HTML, so would not expect it to work on MathML tags, and tests suggests the same.

When you use MathML within HTML, you can wrap a `math` element inside an HTML container that is editable, say `<div contenteditable><math ...>...</math></div>`. However, although this makes the text editable, it seems to be editable as text only. When you have, say, `<mi>A</mi>` and you edit in a browser by replacing the A by B, then it becomes just B in the document tree, a character with no markup (and therefore appearing in upright style, not italic).

So basically the answer appears to be “no.”

Answer (score 0):

There is another option that works in Chromium browsers at least.

Still not clear on what exactly is required or not prohibited by the spec, but this worked like a charm for me.

```html
<math display="block">
    <mrow>
      <munderover>
        <mo>∑</mo>
        <mrow>
          <mi><span contenteditable>n</span></mi>
          <mo>=</mo>
          <mn><span contenteditable>1</span></mn>
        </mrow>
        <mrow>
          <mo><span contenteditable>+</span></mo>
          <mn><span contenteditable>∞</span></mn>
        </mrow>
      </munderover>
      <mfrac>
        <mn><span contenteditable>1</span></mn>
        <msup>
          <mi><span contenteditable>n</span></mi>
          <mn><span contenteditable>2</span></mn>
        </msup>
      </mfrac>
    </mrow>
  </math>
```

Slap a little javascript on that to suit your needs and Bob's your uncle. :-)

Answer (score -3):

here you will have the idea of the given content editable elements

[Content Editable in HTML 5](http://html5demos.com/contenteditable)

[Also Check the code for the same](http://html5demos.com/contenteditable#view-source)

Hope this one you needed.